# Wordpress + nginx (post compromise), best way to block POST request for random php script?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, security

Due to an outdated plugin, one of the domains that I host on my VPS was compromised and there were bots POSTing to //listTT9.php in order to send mail.

The plugin was updated, I've gone through all of the code in the Wordpress install and resolved all the compromised code but there are still bots trying to POST against //listTT9.php.

My question is, are there any suggestions on how to deal with this? Looking through the logs, it's a plethora of IPs, so just blocking the IPs with something like fail2ban wouldn't really do *that* much good. I've thought about doing something similar to the following:

```
#Block spammers requesting listTT9.php:
  location ~* /listTT9\.php$ {
    return 410; #410 means "GONE" according to this: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
  }
```

But it doesn't really seem to make a difference.

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Ignore it? Not a whole lot you can do. Eventually the "bots" will give up.

Comment: The best way is simply ignore it. It won't bother you. I tested that configuration and it gives return code **410**. So, what do you mean by "it doesn't really seem to make a difference" ?

Comment: "So, what do you mean by "it doesn't really seem to make a difference" "

Basically (surprise surprise) the bots ignore the fact that the content has been removed, and I continue to get POST requests for that content multiple times per minute. I agree that it really doesn't harm anything, but it's just.... obnoxious? Thank you for your feedback though.